# Number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am relatively new to SQL and I keep getting the following error "The number of columns in the foreign-key referencing list is not equal to the number of columns in the referenced list."

```
create table client
(name varchar(30),
 phone int,
 city varchar(20),
 state char(2) CHECK(state='MN' OR state='ND' OR state='SD' OR state='WI' or state='IA'),
 primary key(name,phone));

create table owns_vehicle
(name varchar(30),
 phone int,
 vin varchar(10),
 primary key(name, phone, vin),
 foreign key(name,phone) references client);

create table service_appointment
(mydate date,
 vin varchar(10),
 mechanic varchar(15),
 description varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 cost int CHECK (cost>=0),
 primary key(mydate,vin),
 foreign key(vin) references owns_vehicle);
```

This is the line that is causing the issue:

```
foreign key(vin) references owns_vehicle);
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to reference `owns_vehicle`, thus you need to reference all of the tables `PRIMARY KEY` columns, which would be `name, phone, vin`. But your foreign key has only `vin`, thus there are two columns (`name, phone`) missing.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key has three parts.  You need to reference all of them.  If you are going to use this model, then you need the other two components:

```
create table service_appointment (
  mydate date,
  name varchar(30),
  phone int,
  vin varchar(10),
  mechanic varchar(15),
  description varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  cost int CHECK (cost>=0),
  primary key(mydate,vin),
  foreign key(name, phone, vin) references owns_vehicle (name, phone, vin)
);
```

However, I think you data model should change.  VINs can change owners.  People can change phone numbers.  These don't seem like good components of a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that a vehicle can only have a single owner at a given time, you can make your current data model work by changing `owns_vehicle` to have a uniqueness constraint on `VIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE OWNS_VEHICLE
  (NAME   VARCHAR2(30),
   PHONE  INT,
   VIN    VARCHAR2(10),
   CONSTRAINT PK_OWNS_VEHICLE
     PRIMARY KEY(NAME, PHONE, VIN)
     USING INDEX,
   CONSTRAINT OWNS_VEHICLE_UQ1
     UNIQUE(VIN)
     USING INDEX,
   CONSTRAINT OWNS_VEHICLE_FK1
     FOREIGN KEY(NAME,PHONE) REFERENCES CLIENT(NAME, PHONE));
```